Which font/setting to correctly display U+2E976 in Firefox and everywhere in Linux
I'm trying to figure out which font I have to install to be able to see the characters on this page:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%AE%A5%B6#Chinese
 which is U+2E976
I'm on Linux Mint. I've installed all the Noto fonts, Unifont, Everson Mono, Microsoft TTF.
Firefox was already set to using Noto, I switched it to Unifont, still nothing. I also can't see the character in other text programs. It always either shows up as the little square with numbers/letters or just as a square with a question mark.
Any help?
thanks


None of the fonts you listed include this character. Try BabelStone Han.
